# What does the error in Program.cs saying "Parameter is not Valid" means?

Tags: c#, image, parameters

I'm still new in c# Please help me. I was trying to save images in database, for that i did this as suggested in my researches:

```
byte[] img = ImageToByte(pbxBarcode.Image);
byte[] img2 = ImageToByte(pbxLogo.Image);

cmd.CommandText = "Update table set Image=(?),logo=(?) where ID=" + id + "";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@barcode", OdbcType.Image).Value = img;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@logo", OdbcType.Image).Value = img2;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

the first data entered will be saved as intended but the program freezes(?) . with that, i mean no EventHandler will fire but objects are still functional, textboxes still accepts input, etc. then if i browse away of the form then return, the error appears in Program.cs saying "Parameter is not Valid". I provided a screenshot.

[image]

also note that if i only provided one odbcParameter.. all if working fine.. I also tried using two Update statements.. even created two functions for each, updatebarcode(id), updatelogo(id) but still no luck. I hope you can help me. tnx

Comment: You should get the full stack trace, and post that as text. The screenshot really shows us *very* little information.

Comment: On which line you get this error? Since I'm at work, I can't see images on tinypic domain.

Comment: @Jon Skeet what is a stack trace? ^_^

Comment: @Soner Gonul here: Application.Run(new UserLogin());

Comment: What are the data types of `Image` and `logo` at the database? For info, if it was me I'd also have used a parameter for `id` - i.e. `where ID=?`

Comment: @ArjunaD'Jishnu no, the exception isn't *happening* there; it is just *appearing* there because you haven't caught it anywhere else. Is this happening in a button-click, for example? If so, you should `catch` the exception there.

Comment: @MarcGravell the data type is image

Comment: A stack trace is the details of the methods on the stack leading up to the exception - what's calling what. It sounds like it may be worth you pausing your current task and doing a bit more research on core debugging / diagnostic skills which would make it much easier for you to help yourself on this problem and future ones.

Comment: What type of database is used?

Comment: see this link it might help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664813/argument-exception-in-the-main-method-winforms

Comment: @Reniuz i'm using sql server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got it .. I think found the error here on the button click event. not sure why:

```
            pbxLogo.Image.Dispose(); //here.. 
            pbxLogo.Image = pbxSelectLogo.Image;
```

but i remove that line and it just worked.. hehe

this is the exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
   at System.Drawing.Image.get_FrameDimensionsList()
   at System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.CanAnimate(Image image)
   at System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.ImageInfo..ctor(Image image)
   at System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.Animate(Image image, EventHandler onFrameChangedHandler)
   at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.Animate(Boolean animate)
   at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.Animate()
   at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.InstallNewImage(Image value, ImageInstallationType installationType)
   at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.set_Image(Image value)
   at xxxxx.BarcodeGenerator.btnStOk_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\xxxxx\xxxxx\BarcodeGenerator.cs:line 459
```

what does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you using sql server you can use SqlCommand. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) is documentatio with example. From documentation: *The Microsoft .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server does not support the question mark (?) placeholder for passing parameters to a SQL Statement or a stored procedure called by a command of CommandType.Text*

So what you may want to use:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Update table set Image=(@barcode),logo=(@logo) where ID=@imageID";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@barcode", SqlDbType.Image).Value = img;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@logo", SqlDbType.Image).Value = img2;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@imageID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
```

Also like others mentioned you getting exception in Program.cs because you didn't handled exception anywhere else.

If you do something like this:

```
try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch(Exception exc) //<==
{

}
```

Visual Studio will break at the place where arrow shows. At this point you can analyse `exc` and you will see error message and stack trace (the thing Jon Skeet was talking about)